# UIWebView not loading web page

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I've been trying to learn iOS development with Swift but I've been stuck trying to load a simple web page for a week or so. I've looked all around and the following code seems to work for others but when I run the iOS simulator nothing shows up but the background for the `UIWebView`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

   let myURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "https://www.google.com")

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: myURL!))
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be using this

```
let myURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
```

not `fileURLWithPath:`.

The issue is that, by using `fileURLWithPath:`, the web view searches the filesystem for a file named `"https://www.google.com"` and doesn't find one, as no such file exists.